# Angular - Error running trying to mock router.events

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, jasmine, observable

I am trying to create a mock for an observable, in this case Router.events. However I seem to be missing something. While running ng test I get the error: TypeError: this.router.events.subscribe is not a function

I have created a simple service to demonstrate the code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { routes } from '../constants/routes';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService {
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
    ) { }

    public result: string = null;

    init() {
        console.log('testService.init');
        let result: string = null;
        this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
            if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                if (event.url === routes.signIn) {
                    result = '1';
                } else if (event.url === routes.modules) {
                    result = '2'
                }
            }
        });

        this.result = result;

    };
}
```

```
    import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
    import { NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { of } from 'rxjs';
    import { routes } from '../constants/routes';
    import { TestService } from './test.service';
    
    describe('TestSevice', () => {
      let service: TestService;
      
    
      const router = jasmine.createSpyObj(['events']);
    
      const navigationEndMock: NavigationEnd = {
        url: null,
        id: 1,
        urlAfterRedirects: '',
        toString: () => '',
      };
    
      beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                {provide: Router, useValue: router}
              ]
        });
        service = TestBed.inject(TestService);
    
      });
    
      it('should be created', () => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
      });
    
      it('if user browses to the sign in page set result to 1', () => {
        // arrange
        console.log('testSpecService');
        navigationEndMock.url = routes.signIn;
        router.events.and.returnValue(of(navigationEndMock));
    
        // act
        service.init();
    
        // assert
        expect(service.result).toBe('1')
      });
    });
```

Any tips on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: jasmine.createSpyObject will not give you an object with an Observable (or anything that you can call subscribe on) inside. you should model you mock object manually and then spy on its functions.

Answer (score 0):

The best way in order to mock dependencies in angular is to use a testing library such as [ng-mocks](https://github.com/ike18t/ng-mocks).

a sandbox with the solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-brook-gwoow?file=/src/test.spec.ts

```js
describe('TestSevice', () => {
  // configuring dependencies and mocks
  beforeEach(() => MockBuilder(TestService).mock(Router));

  it('if user browses to the sign in page set result to 1', () => {
    // creating a fake stream for Router.events
    const events$ = new ReplaySubject<NavigationEnd>(1);
    MockInstance(Router, 'events', events$);

    // creating the service
    const service = MockRender(TestService).point.componentInstance;

    // simulating navigation
    events$.next(MockService(NavigationEnd, {
      id: 1,
      toString: () => '',
      url: routes.signIn,
      urlAfterRedirects: '',
    }));

    // act
    service.init();

    // assert
    expect(service.result).toBe('1');

    // simulating navigation
    events$.next(MockService(NavigationEnd, {
      id: 2,
      toString: () => '',
      url: routes.modules,
      urlAfterRedirects: '',
    }));

    // act
    service.init();

    // assert
    expect(service.result).toBe('2');
  });
});
```